# Non-artinian center

Tags: ring-theory

Recall that an Artinian ring is a ring that satisfies the descending chain condition on ideals. What is an example of an Artinian ring whose center is non-Artinian?

Comment: I don't have a specific example, but it's probably helpful to remember that an Artinian integral domain is a field. That makes it pretty easy to find non-Artinian commutative rings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be simpler examples, but in Lemma 2.2 of
"[Centres and fixed-point rings of artinian rings](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01214261)" by Christian U. Jensen and Søren Jøndrup (Mathematische Zeitschrift
 130, 189-197 (1973)) it's shown that if $k$ is a field and $V$ a $k$-vector space of dimension at least the cardinality of $k$, then the ring $R=k\oplus V$, where $V$ is a square zero ideal, is the centre of an artinian ring. So long as $\dim_k(V)$ is infinite, $R$ is not artinian.